# FaceDetect OpenCV sample code not working on MSV C++ 2008 v9

Tags: opencv

I installed opencv2.0 and I am using MSV c++ 2008 v9. I tested some code online that return the inverted version of a singel static image, but I would like to see the FaceDetect code working as well. I tried following the instructions in the [wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection#HowtomaketheFaceDetectorworkinMFCApplication.3A) but I get a memory alocation error coming from a file I am not supposed to edit. I wanted to know if anyone wants to or has tried doing this and could share some insight into how to accomplish the test of this already provided code. My main problem at the moment is that there is a lot of junk out there about working with openCv1.0~ and other versions of MVS, but I want specifics to my version.

Thanks for the help in advance,

Bc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already installed OpenCV2.0 and compiled it using MSV C++ 2008 successfully. Now to execute already provided code you can either directly execute the facedetect.exe command located at "C:\OpenCV2.0\vs2008\bin\Debug\" assuming you have installed OpenCV2.0 in it's default location.

Syntax : facedetect --cascade="C:\OpenCV2.0\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" "C:\OpenCV2.0\samples\c\lena.jpg"

**OR**
You can execute facedetect.exe from "C:\OpenCV2.0\samples\c\" path. specify the cascade classifier name and image.

Syntax : facedetect --cascade="C:\OpenCV2.0\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" lena.jpg